# 'style' does not exist on 'Element' when using strict type checking

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code with strict type checking for Javascript using `jsconfig.json`

**jsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "checkJs": true
    }
}
```

Now, when I use `document.getElementsByClassName()`, I can't set all properties that I want -- because the function returns `Element` and not `HTMLElement`.

**main.js**

```
let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button")
let btn = buttons[0]
btn.style.color = "red"
```

> Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'

Strictly speaking this error is correct: `Element` has no style property so that's why I can't adjust it.

In Typescript, Java or C# there's the option to tell the compiler the type:

```
let btn = buttons[0] as HTMLElement
```

Is there a way in Javascript to treat `Element` as `HTMLElement`?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: How to solve this IDE warning in vanilla javascript. `Element` has no style property, that's why the IDE complains when I adjust the style. But I know that it's actually HTMLElement, which does have style...

Comment: I'm not getting the error. Maybe any extension is doing so. run `code  --disable-extensions`  and try again.  Let me know.

Comment: You're right, if I start a new project I don't get the error either. Must be a "strict" setting somewhere....

Comment: OK, I found the config setting that causes this. I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: What wast the config's property that caused it?
I guess that'll be helpful for others who faced the same issue in future.

Answer (score -1):

Give it a try:

```
btn.style("color", "red");
```

Comment: This works, but the actual problem is that I would like my IDE to interpret `btn` as a `HTMLElement`.

Comment: Strictly speaking there is an error, because I try to adjust style on `Element`. But `Element` has no style, that is why vscode shows this warning.

Answer (score -1):

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) says, that .item() method returns a DOM node.

If IDE follows the spec, then the approach is:

```
btn = menuButtons.item(0);
```

Comment: I didn't know that, but `item()` still returns `Element`. You can see that in the docs too: `(method) HTMLCollectionOf<Element>.item(index: number): Element`

Comment: I mean the documentation on MDN, which says the following about .item() method:
"Returns the specific node at the given zero-based index into the list. Returns null if the index is out of rang"

Comment: @RitwickDey You are correct if you mean that there is no Error when running the code. But the IDE warning is also correct. We are calling a property on an object that does not have that property. In most other programming languages there is a way to tell the IDE what kind of object we are dealing with, so I wonder how to do this in Javascript.

Comment: @ViacheslavMoskalenko you mean https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/item ? Because that says a NodeList contains a Node.

Comment: @Kokodoko, not NodeList, but rather HTMLCollection (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), because that is what returned from getElementsByClassName() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: @ViacheslavMoskalenko yes, but doesnt `HTMLCollection.item()` return a `Node` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node

Comment: @Kokodoko, from the official documentation on .item() method of HTMLCollection: "Returns the specific node at the given zero-based index into the list. Returns null if the index is out of range." (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). The thing is that Element inherits from Node.

Comment: Yes, and HTMLElement inherits from Element. But even if the actual returned node is an HTMLElement, the editor won't allow properties of HTMLElement. You can try it yourself by pasting my three lines of code in the https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html (typescript behaves the same as javascript with strict type checking enabled)

Comment: Yes, it does highlight the above mentioned snippet with red.
As an alternative one might want to install custom typings, where a set of methods that is being used in a project (for example, getElementsByClassName) are returning a values of expected type.
The thing is that official typings from Microsoft (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts) for DOM api contains that for getElementsByClassName:
"getElementsByClassName(classNames: string): HTMLCollectionOf<Element>;"

Comment: The problem is very simple: `getElementById()` returns `Element`. Which is correct. `Element` is a parent for all kinds of elements, such as `HTMLElement`. My question is, how to tell the IDE that the returned `Element` is actually a `HTMLElement`. In Typescript (or C#) you can simply say `let el = ... as HTMLElement`.